# Play Framework change GuiceOneAppPerSuite to GuiceOneAppPerTest

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to change the application trait instance  Test from `GuiceOneAppPerSuite` to `GuiceOneAppPerTest`. Because with `GuiceOneAppPerSuite`, is difficult to test the database since the tests are changing the data with not sequential order. I think the best option is to change the interface and get the database dropped and created in each test.

This is the original file

```
trait MyAppOneApp extends PlaySpec with Results with GuiceOneAppPerSuite with MockitoSugar {

  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = app.injector.instanceOf[ExecutionContext]

  implicit val sys = ActorSystem("MyTest")
  implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()

  val dataSource = PRODUCTION

  implicit override lazy val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .in(Mode.Test)
    .overrides(myAppModule)
    .build()

  // Repositories
  val itemRepository = app.injector.instanceOf[ItemRepositoryImpl]

  // Services
  val itemService = app.injector.instanceOf[ItemServiceImpl]

  //Controllers
  val itemController = app.injector.instanceOf[ItemController]

}
```

When I try to change for this

```
trait MyAppOneApp extends PlaySpec with Results with GuiceOneAppPerTest with MockitoSugar {

  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = app.injector.instanceOf[ExecutionContext]

  implicit val sys = ActorSystem("MyTest")
  implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()

  val dataSource = PRODUCTION

  override def newAppForTest(td: TestData) = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .in(Mode.Test)
    .overrides(myAppModule)
    .build()

  // Repositories
  val itemRepository = app.injector.instanceOf[ItemRepositoryImpl]

  // Services
  val itemService = app.injector.instanceOf[ItemServiceImpl]

  //Controllers
  val itemController = app.injector.instanceOf[ItemController]

}
```

I get a NullPointerException

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:
[info]   at functional.common.MyAppOneApp.$init$(MyAppOneApp.scala:25)
[info]   at functional.models.repositories.implementations.ItemRepositoryImplSpec.<init>(ItemRepositoryImplSpec.scala:9)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[info]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[info]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[info]   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
[info]   at org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestTask.execute(Framework.scala:435)
[info]   at sbt.ForkMain$Run.lambda$runTest$1(ForkMain.java:304)
[info]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

Comment: Same for me... any clue or any idea on how to fix this ?

Comment: @N.Martignole thank you for reading, no clue up to the moment, but if anything happens I will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using GuiceOneAppPerTest, you will need to inject the instance into each test. 
So,

```
  // Services
  val itemService = app.injector.instanceOf[ItemServiceImpl]

  //Controllers
  val itemController = app.injector.instanceOf[ItemController]
```

needs to be inside the test.